# CMS control or tool that I can also input conditional logic like in the ReportViewer (rdlc) control

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, reportviewer

I am trying to revamp the way my company's portal displays some of its "static" content.  It is a bloated C# web forms portal made from scratch.  Moving it to a pure CMS type portal like Sharepoint is impossible.  Anytime we need to update our more "static" pages me have to go through a huge project process which then leads to a huge deploy of the whole website just for some "static" content changes.  I qualiy "static" because behind the scenes there is some logic on whethere or not to display certain parts of the content depending on the user's role or the user's line of business.  So, some content can be displayed for everyone and other small parts are conditional.

Can anyone point me to a some type of control or CMS tool like the ReportViewer control that, for the sake of brevity, has a conditional parameter for the "visible" property?  The condition would have to come from some value in the database.  Like `Visible = if (LineOfBusiness == "Agricuture")` (then it would be visible to the user from an ag type company and not display if the user's company was in insurance).  I hope someone here in this great community can help me out.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you add custom code to the global.asax.cs to dynamically set roles that represent line of business etc., you can use security trimming on a web.sitemap.